# Grouping lat and long into smaller areas/radius to get total within the radius in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, geocoding

I have a long list of longitude and latitude of places. So I would like to group the long and lat into smaller area lets say 100m radius and get total count from long and lat within that area/radius.

```
Example table:

id  lat         long         total
1   1.5021033   103.6241121  1
2   1.502434    103.6439708  1
3   3.1319197   101.6840589  1

Desired result:
lat     long      total
1.502   103.624   2
3.132   101.684   1
```

Based on what I read from GIS wiki (http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Decimal_degrees), the radius can change based on the decimal point. So my question would be is it enough to round the long and lat to 3 decimal if I wanted to group the location by 100m radius?

```py
# Example of code snippet

import pandas as pd

header = ['id', 'lat', 'long', 'total']
content = [[1,1.5021033,103.6241121,1], [2,1.502434,103.6239708,1], [3,3.1319197,101.6840589,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns=header)

df['lat'] = df['lat'].round(decimals = 3)
df['long'] = df['long'].round(decimals = 3)
display(df.drop(columns='id').groupby(by=["lat", "long"]).count())
```

Is the solution as simple as this without losing too much of the accuracy (within the 100m radius)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounding up to 3 decimal places is about 111 meters so it is not much accurate, you have to use a more precise method and it is using geospatial libraries. Here is the updated version of your code and more precise.

```py
from geopy.distance import geodesic
import pandas as pd

header = ['id', 'lat', 'long', 'total']
content = [[1, 1.5021033, 103.6241121, 1], [2, 1.502434, 103.6239708, 1], [3, 3.1319197, 101.6840589, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns=header)

# Define a function to calculate the distance between two coordinates
def calculate_distance(coord1, coord2):
    return geodesic(coord1, coord2).meters

# Group the locations based on their proximity within a 100-meter radius
grouped = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    found = False
    for i, group in enumerate(grouped):
        if calculate_distance((row['lat'], row['long']), (group[0], group[1])) <= 100:
            grouped[i][2] += 1
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        grouped.append([row['lat'], row['long'], 1])

# Create a new DataFrame with the grouped locations
result_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped, columns=['lat', 'long', 'total'])
print(result_df)
```